JAVA - I want to ignore the image showing on drag element
I using in my app DragSource to drag and drop elements.
When I started to drag the element I saw a preview image of it and wanted to ignore it.
I do not want to show this preview, how can I do it ?
img1
red - original place
yellow - a preview I did that needs to be drop
green ( the one that I don't want to show ) - looks like copy of the element.
another example:
img2
red- original
green - the one I don't want to show.
